# Set environment variables for Pycharm Github Console

Tags: git, pycharm, console

## Set environment variables for Pycharm Github Console

#### Issue presentation:

I have a `pre-commit-config.yaml` file that runs a python test:

```yaml
      - id: pytest-0
        name: test
        entry: poetry run pytest tests/
        language: system
        pass_filenames: false
        always_run: true
```

This `pre-commit` hook runs always as a condition to confirm the commit. Those tests require some credentials existing as environment variables in the `pre-commit` execution console.

When doing this process through PyCharm UI (commit and push) the `pre-commit` hooks are executed inside of PyCharm Git Console. I've been researching how to do in order to **configure environment variables to PyCharm Git Console.**

#### What I tried?

When commit and push in a terminal initiated with the environment variables like this:

```bash
git add file.py
git commit -m 'some awesome message'
```

It runs normally!

Instead, when I use the Git UI of PyCharm I try to commit and push changes but the environment variables are not recognized. I tried with settings in **Settings > Version Control > Git** but found nothing.

I would like to be able to set environment variables for the Git console in PyCharm or at least chose the console that runs Git commands.